# Org-mode: How to render latex inside ~code~

Tags: org-mode, latex

This seems a catch-22: I want to render code in an org-mode export (html or latex pdf) where the snippet below done as a `~`code block

```
> (cons 1 nil) \to (1)
```

actually renders `\to` as a proper right arrow (yields). Of course if I do the snippet as inline latex

```
$> (cons 1 nil) \to (1)$
```

I get the properly rendered right arrow, but now it's not in the sans mono code font. What can I do to have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: Why not just use the Unicode character? `→`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use one of the following:

```
~> (cons 1 nil)~ \to ~(1)~

~> (cons 1 nil) → (1)~
```

Comment: Could you explain how you insert the arrow character? (input method I guess)

Comment: @JeanPierre, as you guessed I used the TeX input method, `C-\ TeX RET \to`. You can also copy and paste from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From org mode [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html#Emphasis-and-monospace):

> You can make words *bold*, /italic/, *underlined*, ‘=verbatim=’ and
>   ‘~code~’, and, if you must, ‘+strike-through+’.  Text in the code and
>   verbatim string is not processed for Org mode specific syntax, it is
>   exported verbatim.

Indeed `~> (cons 1 nil) \to (1)~` is exported as LaTeX `\texttt{> (cons 1 nil) \textbackslash{}to (1)}`.

But this does suggest a workaround for LaTeX: use an export [filter](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html#Advanced-configuration) to undo the conversion of `\` to `\textbackslash{}`.

```el
(defun my-latex-filter-allow-latex-in-code (text backend info)
  "Undo backslash escaping"
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "textbackslash{}" "" text)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-code-functions
         #'my-latex-filter-allow-latex-in-code)
```

The export filter can be extended for handling html as well.  Here's a first draft handling only `\to`:

```el
(defun my-filter-allow-latex-in-code (text backend info)
  "Allow LaTeX symbols in code"
  (cond 
   ((org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "textbackslash{}" "" text))
   ((org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    ;; either extend this or find the html export function doing these conversions
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\to" "&rarr;" text))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-code-functions
         #'my-filter-allow-latex-in-code)
```